Is correctness condition of ABE scheme of [BGG+'Eurocrypt2014] right?
I'm reading page 16 of [BGG+'Eurocrypt2014, Section 4]. The ABE in this paper is one of the best lattice-based ABE scheme so far and the techniques used in it inspired other cryptographic primitives too (like, designing (constrained) PRF, signature, ...). Here is the image of the correctness



I want to know the upper-bound of the noise vector in the following vector
$$\mathbf{c}'_{f}=(\mathbf{c}_{in}|\mathbf{c}_{f})=(\mathbf{A}|\mathbf{B}_{f}+y\mathbf{G})^{T}
\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{e}', \mathrm{where}\ \|\mathbf{e}'\|<\Delta+\chi_{\mathsf{max}}<
{\color{red}{(\alpha_{\mathcal{F}}+1)\chi_{\mathsf{max}}}}$$
In the following, I briefly introduce the notation.
We have $\mathbf{c}_{in}=\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{e}_{0}$ where $\mathbf{e}_{0}\leftarrow\chi$ from a $\chi_{\mathsf{max}}-$bounded distribution.
And, $\mathbf{c}_{f}\leftarrow\mathsf{Eval}_{\mathsf{ct}}(f,\{(x_{i},\mathbf{B}_{i},\mathbf{c}_{i})\}_{i=1}^{\ell})$
where $\mathbf{c}_{i}\in E_{\mathbf{s},\delta}(x_{i},\mathbf{B}_{i})$ which means $\mathbf{c}_{i}=(\mathbf{B}_{i}+x_{i}\mathbf{G})^{T}\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{e}_{i}\mod q$ where $\|\mathbf{e}_{i}\|\leq\delta$.
By $\mathsf{Eval}_{\mathsf{ct}}$ algorithm, $\mathbf{c}_{f}\in E_{\mathbf{s},\Delta}(f(\mathbf{x}),\mathbf{B}_{f})$ which means $\mathbf{c}_{f}=(\mathbf{B}_{f}+f(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{G})^{T}{\mathbf{s}}+\mathbf{e}_{f}$ where $\|\mathbf{e}_{f}\|\leq\Delta<\alpha_{\mathcal{F}}\cdot\delta$.
I think authors forgot that in the scheme $\mathbf{c}_{i}=(\mathbf{B}_{i}+x_{i}\mathbf{G})^{T}\mathbf{s}+ {\color{blue}{\mathbf{S}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{e}_{0}}}\mod q$
where $\mathbf{S}_{i}\leftarrow\{\pm1\}^{m\times m}$. Now we have $\delta=\|\mathbf{S}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{e}_{0}\|\leq \|\mathbf{S}_{i}^{T}\|_{2}\cdot\|\mathbf{e}_{0}\|$. By lemma 2.5 in the paper, the spectral norm $\|\mathbf{S}_{i}\|_{2}\leq20\sqrt{m}$ when $\mathbf{S}_{i}\leftarrow\{\pm1\}^{m\times m}$. (Spectral norm intuitively says hom much a matrix streches a vector as a linear transformation). So we have $\delta\leq20\sqrt{m}\chi_{\mathsf{max}}$.
Finally, for $\mathbf{e}'=\mathbf{e}_{0}+\mathbf{e}_{f}$ we must have $\|\mathbf{e}'\|<\Delta+\chi_{\mathsf{max}}<
{\color{blue}{(20\sqrt{m}\alpha_{\mathcal{F}}+1)\chi_{\mathsf{max}}}}$.
Is my argument correct? I'll appreciate any helpful comments and explanations in advance.

I agree with you. The error vector in $c_i$ is $S_i^T e_0$, therefore, the length of the vector is at most $\delta \leq 20 \sqrt{m} \chi_{\max}$. Due to this, we would need to change the bound on $\alpha_{\mathcal{F}}^2 \cdot m$ for correctness to hold, right?

Yes, you're right. That's a good point. For using their scheme (knowing the upper bound of the error vector), I didn't need that part, though. I think few people working on these kinds of subjects and some researchers just using the scheme without verifying it.

Why $\alpha_{\mathcal{F}}>\sqrt{n\log_{2}m}$? And also, how do they write $1+2m\sigma+2m\sigma\alpha_{\mathcal{F}}\leq3\alpha_{\mathcal{F}}^{2}m$?

I believe it should be $\alpha_{\mathcal{F}} = \omega(\sqrt{n \log q \log m})$. Then, we get $1 + 2m\sigma (1 + \alpha_{\mathcal{F}}) \leq 1 + 2m (c \sqrt{n \log q \log m}) (1 + \alpha_{\mathcal{F}}) \leq 1 + 2m \alpha_{\mathcal{F}}^2 \leq 3m\alpha_{\mathcal{F}}^2$. We used $\sigma = \omega(\sqrt{n \log q \log m})$ due to $\mathsf{KeyGen}_{\mathsf{FKHE}}$.
